# Reordering of a sequence of points

Tags: algorithms

Given a finite sequence of points $\{\boldsymbol{\alpha}_k\}_{k=1}^m$, here $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_k\in \mathbb{R}^n$. My question is:

> How to find a reordering of $\{\boldsymbol{\alpha}_k\}_{k=1}^m$ such that
>   $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^m|\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{\tau_k}-\boldsymbol{\alpha}_k|$$
>   reaches to **MAX**. Here $\{\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{\tau_k}\}_{k=1}^m$ is the reordering and $|\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{\tau_k}-\boldsymbol{\alpha}_k|$ means the Euclidean distance between $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{\tau_k}$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_k$?

Please give an algorithm with time complexity as low as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially equivalent to solving the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) (with the Euclidean metric), which is NP-hard. So, it is almost certain that no efficient algorithm can be found.